# Add image from library at specific coordinates

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have 500x500px images in my Library that I want to load to a specific set of coordinates. I've found various hints on how to insert images programatically, but none state how to insert to a specific location.

Currently, my code goes something like this:

```
var image:Bitmap;
switch(conStyle){
  case 4:
   var chart:IF= new IF(); //Flash CS5 doesn't need the dimensions passed on
   image= new Bitmap(IF);
}
```

However, this sets the default location to the upper left corner.  How can I set the xy coordinates for the image to be displayed at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image should have x and y variables that you set to whatever you wish.

```
image= new Bitmap(IF);
image.x = 50;
```

Positive X values move to the right.  Negative to the left

Positive Y values move down.  Negative upwards.